# Objective-C - Immutable declaration inside if - Scope and Memory Management?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, scope, nsdate, immutability

In the Apple Documentation, it is stated that NSDate objects are immutable which I presume means that once they are initialised with a value, they cannot/shouldn't be changed.

However, in the following code I need an NSDate to be one of two possible values so naturally i might use:

```
for (class* object in array) {

        if (i == 0) {
            NSDate* fromDate = //...a date
        } else {
            NSDate* fromDate = //...a different date
        }

        //Use fromDate
        i++ 

    }
```

As far as I'm aware, this is not valid because using fromDate outside the if block is outside of scope.

The solution would normally be:

```
    for (class* object in array) {

        NSDate* fromDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        if (i == 0) {
            fromDate = //...a date
        } else {
            fromDate = //...a different date
        }

        //Use then release fromDate
        i++ 

    }
```

However, according to the Apple Docs, when an NSDate receives 'init' it's initialised with todays date and since it's immutable, I can't reassign it.

What's the correct thing to do here? Is it simply to copy all of my code into the if blocks twice? Or have I misunderstood the term immutable? Or perhaps I need a retain after the assignment in the first example?

thanks

Comment: Your terminology suggests that you might misunderstand immutability. `fromDate` is nothing more than a pointer, it can be reused as often as you like within its scope. The objects assigned to it, like the NSDate here, may be immutable, meaning they cannot be changed after creation. An immutable object cannot be modified, but a pointer to an immutable object can be reassigned to another object of the same class. This is an extremely important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate * fromDate = nil;
if (i == 0) {
  fromDate = //...a date
} else {
  fromDate = //...a different date
}
```

Your question also reveals a fundamental misunderstanding of how pointers work.  Yes, the documentation says that `NSDate` objects are immutable.  But `fromDate` is not an `NSDate`.  It is an `NSDate*`.  In other words, it is simply a forwarding address that points to where the actual `NSDate` object lives.  The pointer itself is mutable (unless it's declared as `const`), and you can feel free to change the *pointer*'s value as much as you like.  However, the thing that the pointer points to (the actual `NSDate`) is correctly immutable.

Comment: The important thing to realise is, that *fromDate* is *not* an object, but a pointer that points to the object. You cannot change the object itself *(NSDate)*, but you can change which object the pointer points to. This means, it's completely valid to do: `NSDate *myDate = aDate; myDate = anotherDate;``

Answer (score 3):

```
    NSDate* fromDate = nil

    if (i == 0) {
        fromDate = //create here
    } else {
        fromDate = //or here
    }
```

You don't have to assign it to anything when you declare the variable.